# if my pc have multiple ip how can i use 2 different ip for 2 windows of program?

Tags: windows-10, window

It is purpose for gaming

this game don't allow to run 2 window on 1 IP

so I think for using 1 IP from  LAN  and another on PCIe card(LTE sim slot)

when I open the game will auto-use main IP right?

how can I set second IP for being used by second window of the game

sorry for my english. it is bad i know

Comment: "when I open the game will auto-use main IP right?" - Most applications do not provide a means to select which network adapter is used.  You will have to confirm the application in question does indeed allow you to configuration which network adapter to use

Comment: if the application cannot select network adapter is used. can i use vm-ware(or any third party) to help me select different ip is used?

Comment: Depends on the requirements of the software in question.  VirtualBox for instance only has support for specific versions of DirectX and Vulcan.  You will also get a huge performance penalty.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this:

- Start one instance of the game with your IP
- Start a VPN session
- Start the second instance of the game that will use another IP from the VPN.

The success of this method depends on how this game works.